# In trigonometry, how can we find the sine/cosine of an angle larger than 90 degrees, if sine and cosine only work for right triangles?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

In trigonometry, how can there be angle thetas larger than 90 degrees, if sine and cosine only work for right triangles? I realize what we do is that we take the sine or cosine of the angle complementary to it. But then, how does that give the ratio between the opposite/adjacent and hypotenuse of the angle larger than 90 degrees? It doesn't! It only gives the ratio between the opposite/adjacent and hypotenuse of the angle complementary to it! Can someone please explain?

Comment: It's an extension of the sine and cosine functions using the properties of the unit circle. Yes, it's true that right triangles' angles don't go past 90, but that still doesn't mean that the functions for those angles can work past 90.

Comment: I think sine and cosine is *defined* particularly on the ratio of the lengths of right triangles and not on non-right triangles. Regarding taking the sine and cosine of obtuse angles, we are not really taking the sine and cosine of the obtuse angle but it is *defined* to be that of the complement of the obtuse angle.

Comment: The right-triangle-based definition of the trigonometric functions is defined  only for angles $\theta$ with radian measure $0 <  \theta < {\large{\frac{\pi}{2}}}$. The more general definition, which works for _all_ values of $\theta$, is based on the coordinates of the point $(x,y)$ where the terminal ray of the angle $\theta$ meets the standard unit circle. For angles $\theta$ such that $0 < \theta < {\large{\frac{\pi}{2}}}$, the general definition yields the same results as the right-triangle-based definition, so for those angles, either definition is applicable.

Comment: @ChristopherMarley So basically, for angles larger than 90, the sine function give the sine of the angle complementary to it?

Comment: @TheLastCipher But then what does it mean it's defined particularly on the ration of the lengths of right triangles, when sine functions "can go past the definition" and be used on obtuse triangles? What meaning does the definition have, one there are triangles and angles that don't obey it?

Comment: I don't think it's "going past definitions". What I meant was, it is **defined** that taking the sine or cosine of any angle past 90 degrees meant you should take the sine or cosine of its complement. It is by definition. The reason textbooks asks you to consider the complement is due to it being defined that way, no more no less. With regards to the motivation, on why it's defined that way, I am not sure why.

Comment: The trigonometric functions were originally defined on the circle.  The right triangle definitions were introduced later.  They are a special case of the general definition.